# Why does this code produce a segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mix(int *a, int *b, int *c, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            c[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i = m - 1; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] % 2 == 1)
        {
            c[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(b[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            c[j] = b[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        if(b[i] % 2 == 1)
        {
            c[j] = b[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    cout << j << ' '; 
}

int main()
{
    int a[10], b[10], c[20], m, n;
    cout << "m: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\nn: ";
    cin >> n;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    mix(a, b, c, m, n);
    for(i = 0; i < (m+n); i++)
    {
        cout << c[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've checked and rechecked the sizes of my arrays and I cannot figure out why the code produces a segfault in the `mix(...)` function. Could it be a problem of using `-O2` optimisation? Furthermore, I've made sure the indices match up. I think the problem is with `c[j] = a[i]`, but I do not understand why that would be causing this segmentation fault.

Comment: What happens when you debug it?

Comment: `for(i = m - 1; i >= 0; i++)` looks suspicious. What's that meant to do?

Comment: Show an example input and expected output

Comment: @TNA thanks, that's where I screwed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for these two loop you were doing `i++` instead of `i--`

```
 for(i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(a[i] % 2 == 1)
        {
            c[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(b[i] % 2 == 1)
    {
        c[j] = b[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```